# how to resize the frame after an event happened?

Tags: java, swing, events, resize, frame

I created a form to choose a database service such as SQL server and Oracle, and its version .then connect to it by clicking the Connect button....but before connection is made, some parameters should be set in order to place in URL...this code is for the Connect button.

```
jButton2 = new JButton();
getContentPane().add(jButton2);
jButton2.setText("Connect");
jButton2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            LinkedFrame inst = new LinkedFrame();
            inst.setLocationRelativeTo(rootPane);
            inst.setVisible(true);
//Question:  Should I add any method here to do what I want? , and what method should I add?
            }
                    });
        }
```

this is the LinkedFrame code(extended from JFrame):

```
    private class DatabaseSelectionHandler implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
        database=jTextField1.getText();
        username=jTextField2.getText();
        pass=new String(jPasswordField1.getPassword());
        if(database.isEmpty() || username.isEmpty() || pass.isEmpty())
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill all fields", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        else
        {   setVisible(false);
            if (service.equalsIgnoreCase("sqlserver"))
                Connector.MSSQLConnection(service);//Single tone connectioto SQL Server
            else
                Connector.ORACLEConnection(service);//Single tone connection to Oracle
//Question:  Should I add any method here to do what I want? , and what method should I add?
        }
    }       
}
```

LinkedFrame is a new form for gathering required information including DB name, Username and Password. these information should be passed to MSSQLconnect or OracleConnect methods fo the Connector Class.In this this form is created as you click the button and disappears as you fill in the fields all and press enter...(see the code above)

Now I have some questions:

I want to resize my main frame(not linkedframe) as soon as I fill in the blanks and heat the ENTER and if the connection is made in order to make queries.

1. What method of JFrame should I use?
2. where should the method be placed(in the button event handler of main frame or in the event handler of Linkedframe or anywhere suggested)?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: it is revised....please check it again...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without more code it may be difficult for us to provide you with a complete answer, but I'll have a go.

Using a static Connector is fine so long as you NEVER want more then one connection at a time.  No issue there really.  If you did however, you would need to pass a `Connector` to the `LinkedFrame`, either as part of the constructor or as property, but that's a design choice.

For the `LinkedFrame`, I would use JDialog set to be `modal`.  This will block the user input until the close the dialog.  This also means that you can show the dialog and your code will be blocked until the dialog is closed.  This provides you a "trap" in your code.

Once the user provides the information you want from the `LinkedFrame` and closes the dialog, you can extract the details you need (if any) and resize your master frame accordingly.

**Update**

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

    LinkedFrame linkedFrame = new LinkedFrame(); // create the dialog, set as modal
    linkedFrame.setVisible(true); // code will block here till you close the dialog

    setSize(width, height); // supply the width & height you want
}
```

Comment: I changed the LinkedFrame to a jDialog and set the modal true in its constructor. now as you said,  my code should be blocked when in button event handler the LinkedFrame is created (the first code block)...I think that the setSize method should be called in the handler of the LinkedFrame, But I dont know how to reach this method there?!!!!

Comment: I'd imagine `linkedFrame.setSize(width, height)` should work just fine, where `linkedFrame` is and instance of your dialog.

Comment: I would like to set Size for my main frame not LinkedFrame...how can I reach to this method from the LinkedFrame class?

Comment: Ah, sorry, you shouldn't really do this.  Once the dialog returns (after you call `setVisible`) you should effect the change within the main frame.

Comment: excuse me but I am not very expert in java...the linkedFrame opens in front of maiFrame, and I want to resize the main frame as soon as dialogbox closes. Please give me a sample code.